# Broken Ubuntu 16.04 installation after upgrade (corrupt kernel?)

Tags: upgrade, kernel

So I chose to manually upgrade our Sony VAIO Tap 20 from Ubuntu 14.04 LTS to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and everything was going just fine, until mid-way through actually installing the upgrade, the screen went black...

I left the computer for a while and then instead of going with my gut, I made the wonderful decision to force the computer off and start again.

Yeah, it was a dumb idea and I should have known better (as soon as did it I was like, "Oh damn, bad move!")... But I guess that's what happens when you're jumping between three upgrading computers at the same time.

Unsurprisingly, my negligence/inattention "broke" Ubuntu...

Now when I select "Ubuntu" on the GRUB menu, I get:

```
[     8.253532] Kernel panic - not synching: Attempted to kill init! exitcode=0x00007f00
[     8.253532]
[     8.253570] CPU: 2 PID: 1 Comm: sh Tainted: G          OX 3.13.0-85-generic #129-Ubuntu
[     8.253597] Hardware name: Sony Corporation SVJ20215CGB/VAIO BIOS R0213F5 04/01/2013
[     8.253623] 0000000000000000 ffff880408d45e48 ffffffff8172b6a7 ffffffff81a50db8
[     8.253650] ffff880403404a80 ffff880408d45ec0 ffffffff8172449b ffffffff00000010
[     8.253676] ffff880408d45ed0 ffff880408d45e70 ffffffff81f25aa0 0000000000007f00
[     8.253704] Call Trace:
[     8.253720] [<ffffffff8172b6a7>] dump_stack+0x64/0x82
[     8.253740] [<ffffffff8172449b>] panic+0xc8/0x1e1
[     8.253760] [<ffffffff8106c721>] do_exit+0xa61/0xa70
[     8.253779] [<ffffffff8106c7af>] do_group_exit+0x3f/0xa0
[     8.253799] [<ffffffff8106c824>] SyS_exit_group+0x14/0x20
[     8.253820] [<ffffffff8173c39d>] system_call_fastpath+0x1a/0x1f
[     8.253864] drm_kms_helper: panic occured, switching back to text console
```

When I select "Advance options for Ubuntu-->Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-85-generic (recovery mode)" on the GRUB menu, I get more or less the same thing (there's a couple of lines which are different, but the last ten or so are the same as above).

Am I right in thinking that this means the kernel has been corrupted when I had the ingenious idea of forcing the computer off and starting again?

Any way to recover from this? Or any other suggestions?

Is there a way I can upgrade Ubuntu without losing my data? Or am I stuck with a "clean" install?

I tried with the disk, but it just wants to "clean" install or "install alongside Ubuntu 16.04"...

Answer (score 1):

[This page](http://www.upubuntu.com/2012/09/how-to-repair-broken-system-after.html) suggests that to fix the issue (a corrupt kernel), one would need to drop to Terminal and purge the old kernel (which is the solution I was expecting, anyway)... But seeing as I cannot even get to Terminal in Recovery Mode, it looks like my foolish mistake is going to cost me a clean install.